# Are there any Lucene stemmers that handle Shakespearean English?

Tags: solr, lucene, nlp, stemming

I'm trying to index some old documents for searching -- 16th, 17th, 18th century.

Modern stemmers don't seem to handle the antiquated word endings: worketh, liveth, walketh.

Are there stemmers that specialize in the English from the time of Shakespeare and the King James Bible? I'm currently using `solr.PorterStemFilterFactory`.

Comment: Do you know any online available dictionary files that work with that old English?

Comment: [The DOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_of_Old_English) reads good, but is work in progress (as of 2015).

Comment: @cheffe I do not, but suppose I did. Is there a way to make a stemmer out of a dictionary file with Solr/Lucene?

Comment: Yes, for Solr the [HunspellStemFilterFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-HunspellStemFilter) or if you are using Lucene the [HunspellStemFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/hunspell/HunspellStemFilter.html) itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [rule changes are minimal](http://snowball.tartarus.org/texts/earlyenglish.html) for that.

So, it might be possible to copy/modify the [PorterStemmer](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_10_1/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/PorterStemmer.java#L269) class and related Factories/Filters.

Or it might be possible to add those specific rules as Regular expression filter before Porter.